# WPF image not rendering after setting source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I am attempting to set the image source in an effort to ultimately pull corporate standard images from what will be a DLL reference.

For testing and to ensure the proper syntax of the Uri, the image was loaded locally to a test project and the source was hard coded in the XAML.

```
<Image Name="imgTest" Source="pack://application:,,,/test2;component/Dictionaries/bricks.png"/>
```

The hardcoded value of imgTest.Source was viewed in debug mode and reads:

```
imgTest.Source = "pack://application:,,,/test2;component/Dictionaries/bricks.png"
```

Next, the source for the image was set in code.

```
BitmapImage imageUri = new BitmapImage();
imageUri.BeginInit();           
var imageSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Dictionaries/bricks.png", UriKind.Absolute);
imageUri.UriSource = imageSource;           
imageUri.EndInit();
imgCopy.Source = imageUri;
```

The softcoded value of imgTest.Source was viewed in debug mode and reads:

```
imgTest.Source = "pack://application:,,,/test2;component/Dictionaries/bricks.png"
```

Both the hard coded and soft coded values are identical however the image does not render with the soft coded configuration.

Updates of the 'Build Action' property for the image have been attempted with Embedded Resource, Content, and Resource in combination with each of the three options available for the 'Copy to Output Directory' property.

Any wisdom on this issue is greatly appreciated.

**Edit # 1**

A side-by-side comparison where I copied the Source property to the soft coded image yields no image being displayed while the hard coded image does yet debug shows identical Source values.  XAML and C# code shown.

```
<Image Name="imgCopy_Soft" />
<Image Name="imgCopy_Hard" Source="Dictionaries/bricks.png" />

imgCopy_Soft.Source = imgCopy_Hard.Source;
```

**Edit # 2** Here is the full XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="test2.ucConfigurator"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="439.5" Width="400">

            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Name="imgCopy_Soft" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Name="imgCopy_Hard" Grid.Column="1" Source="pack://application:,,,/test2;component/Dictionaries/bricks.png" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind it:

```
namespace test2
{
public partial class ucConfigurator : UserControl
{
    public ucConfigurator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        BitmapImage imageUri = new BitmapImage();
        imageUri.BeginInit();
        var imageSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Dictionaries/bricks.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        imageUri.UriSource = imageSource;

        imageUri.EndInit();

        imgCopy_Soft.Source = imageUri;
        imgCopy_Soft.Source = imgCopy_Hard.Source;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you shipping the DLL along side the exe or are you trying to embed the DLL into the exe?

Comment: What type of DLL holds the images? Is it a C# Resource Library or C# User Control Library?

Comment: Make sure that `bricks.png` is a file in a project folder `Dictionaries` in a VS project that builds an assembly named `test2`. The Build Action of the file must be `Resource`. The `Copy to Output Directory` setting is irrelevant, because Build Action `Resource` results in an "assembly resource", i.e. a file that is included in the assembly file. If `test2` is an assembly other than the one where you execute the code, also make sure that it is referenced.

Comment: The DLL will ultimately be embedded in the .exe.  Testing at this time does not rely upon a DLL reference.  The png image has been loaded to the test project directly.

Comment: First step for me is to try and figure out why the identical Uri source definitions are not behaving the same.  The hard code version displays the image while the soft code does not.  If I can resolve this, based on research already done, the embedded DLL effort should not present any additional headaches

Comment: Show more code of how you are implementing this "soft" vs "hard" coding of the source.

Comment: What more could there be?  The path used by the Uri is displayed and loaded in to the Source property.  What was provided is all there is.  This was done in a sandbox project just to proof it out.

Comment: Seems like quite a bit of work for nothing. You are either going to access the image from a DLL, access from shipped loose files, or access from an embedded resource. What is there to proof out as all of those are easy to do.

Comment: I agree that they should be easy to do which is why I am baffled as to why the image loaded by the C# code is not being displayed though all debug values appear identical.  That is the reason for this post.

Comment: Then you are doing something very wrong in your application someplace. I created a quick application with an image and was able to easily get it to render 4 different ways. DLL, Embedded DLL, Loose File, Embedded File. I also also tested both an XAML reference and a dynamic reference from the code behind and it worked just fine. Again, you must be doing something wrong in in your application some place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197233/discussion-between-galactic-and-david-bentley).

Comment: Will take this updated code and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

First, the DLL needs to be added as a `References` in Visual Studio:

[image]

I created a library project inside the same solution and named it _ImageLibrary. I then checked the box for it so it will be added to my project like so:

[image]

Inside the DLL, I set the image to this:

[image]

I have an image called `awesome-cat.jpg`. It is inside of a project directory called `Resources`.

[image]

I can then access it like so:

`<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ImageLibrary;component/Resources/awesome-cat.jpg"/>`

REMEMBER!!! The portion of the XAML above shows the ASSEMBLY NAME and NOT the project name!!!! My assembly is ImageLibrary.dll.

Now if you HAVE the DLL as a loose file, just add it to your project and then reference that in `References` using the `Browse` feature.

It should be noted, this will only work if the DLL is shipped along side your exe. If you want to embed the DLL, then that is a whole different ball game and I can show you how to do that if you ask a separate question for it.